# How can I make TalkBack ignore android:text element?

Tags: android, xml, textview, accessibility, talkback

I am improving the accessibility for visually impaired in my android app. I have the following TextView in a popover.xml file in my Android project.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:text="@string/pass_code"/>
```

Whenever I test the app with TalkBack, the app speaks back the string in `android:text` but in this case I don't want it to be spoken at all because this is a popover window so I would rather want it to be spoken as soon as the window pops over. So I've got `android:contentDescription="@string/pass_code"` in my root LinearLayout which speaks out the same string.

I've tried to set `android:contentDescription="@null"` and I've also tried adding `tools:ignore="ContentDescription"` but neither of them worked. The element in android:text is always spoken. How can I change the TextView so TalkBack will ignore the android:text element?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can hide a view from accessibility services by setting `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` in your layout XML. See the developer docs for [View.setImportantForAccessibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setImportantForAccessibility(int)) for more details.